# How to determine the closest common ancestor class

Tags: python, inheritance, lowest-common-ancestor

Suppose I have four classes: `A`, `B` derived from `A`, `C` derived from `A`, and `D` derived from `C`. (So I always have single inheritance.)
In python, what is the best way to determine the closest common ancestor of any two (instances of such) classes? Specifically, I need a function `clcoancl(X,Y)` for which `clcoancl(A, B) == A`, `clcoancl(B, C) == A`, and `clcoancl(C, D) == C`.

Comment: Why do you need to know, specifically? There might be an easier way to deal with this. Usually just relying on the MRO is enough.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Currently it concerns applications of a binary operation `*` between instances of these classes: `a * a`, `b * c`, `c * d`. This binary operator is defined in `A` and may be refined in the inheriting classes. I would like to easily be able to use the operator as defined in the closest common ancestor class.

Comment: It sounds like your code might have a suboptimal design. You should explain why you are doing this.

Comment: @MikeGraham: Well, `A` is a general class of (mathematical) functions, essentially mappings to rational numbers; when doing pointwise operations, e.g., addition, of functions with different domain, the default approach is to only let this operation be defined on their intersection. The other classes (`B`, `C`, and `D`) are specific types of functions. For some one can take the union of the domains (assuming a function is zero outside its domain) when doing pointwise binary operations. Others need to be normalized in some way after applying the operation to stay within the class.

Comment: @equaeghe, It sounds like your re-use of class inheritance here to reflect this hierarchy could prove more trouble than help. You are asking a lot of it.

Comment: Based on your warnings, I've decided to keep things simple and not go beyond what `isinstance` can give me. I cannot really judge which answer is best, but I'm choosing sr2222's because its greater generality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for single or multiple inheritance, with any number of classes as input:

```
import inspect
from collections import defaultdict

def clcoancl(*cls_list):
    mros = [list(inspect.getmro(cls)) for cls in cls_list]
    track = defaultdict(int)
    while mros:
        for mro in mros:
            cur = mro.pop(0)
            track[cur] += 1
            if track[cur] == len(cls_list):
                return cur
            if len(mro) == 0:
                mros.remove(mro)
    return None # or raise, if that's more appropriate
```

As both NPE and Daniel Rossman have mentioned though, this is probably not the optimal solution to your root problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
class A(object): pass
class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass
class D(C): pass

# get the list of ancestors (assuming single inheritance!)
def ancl(cls):
    ret = []
    while cls is not object:
        ret.append(cls)
        cls = cls.__bases__[0]
    ret.append(object)
    return ret

def clcoancl(cls1, cls2):
    ancl1 = ancl(cls1)
    ancl2 = ancl(cls2)
    # find the first class present in both ancl1 and ancl2
    while len(ancl1) > 0 and len(ancl2) > 0 and ancl1[-1] == ancl2[-1]:
        ret = ancl1.pop(-1)
        ancl2.pop(-1)
    return ret

print clcoancl(A, B)
print clcoancl(B, C)
print clcoancl(C, D)
```

Whether you actually need this is a different matter, as pointed out by @DanielRoseman is his comment to your question.